# Proper Namespacing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, psr-0

I'm trying to namespace my Models in Laravel, and also have them be autoloaded automagically like the normal models do in the root of app/models. `composer dump-autoload` works, but I don't want to run that after I create a new model.

```
#app/models/MyNamespace/Thing.php
<?php
namespace App\Models\MyNamespace;
class Thing {
    // ...
}

#app/routes.php
<?php
Route::get('test', function(){
    $thing = new App\Models\MyNamespace\Thing;
});
```

If I run `composer dump-autoload` everything is fine, otherwise I get a class not found exception.

What can I do to make that kind of structure work without rebuilding the classmap every time I make a new class? I think PSR-0 is where your namespaces correlate directly with your directory structure, and it appears as though my classes are adhering to that...

I've also tried using the Workbench which works great, but ideally I'd like to have, for ex: app/models/MyNamespace, app/models/AnotherNamespace.

Comment: I'd guess this is because the difference of case in `app/App` and `model/Model`. If you are on a Unix environment, PHP is case sensitive for directory names...

Comment: I have tried both ways and neither made a difference (on my Mac at home or Windows at work) unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a Laravel 'problem', this is something that will work, exactly the same way, on every application that uses Composer.

If your classes are following the psr-0 rules (directory structure matters!), you can configure it in your composer.json

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"MyNamespace\\": "app/models"}
    }
}
```

Execute

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Once and it it will show in your autoload_namespaces.php. After that Composer will be able to find your classes by its namespaces, no need to `dump-autoload` again.

To explain better how it works. If you do

```
"psr-0": {"MyNamespace\\": "app/models"}
```

You must use it this way:

```
$user = new MyNamespace\User.php
```

Because Composer adds your namespace to the end of your namespace path and it will expect to find User.php in

```
/var/www/yourappdir/app/models/MyNamespace/User.php
```

So, by doing

```
"psr-0": { "App\\Models\\": "" }
```

You are telling Composer that ALL `/var/www/yourappdir/App/Models` subfolders can contain namespaced files of the App\Models namespace. And you'll be able to address files like:

```
$user = new App\Models\User.php  
$user = new App\Models\MyNamespace\User.php  
$user = new App\Models\MyNamespace\Foo\Bar\User.php
```

And if you do

```
"psr-0": { "App\\Foo": "" }
```

Composer will be able to address those namespaces

```
/var/www/yourappdir/App/Foo
/var/www/yourappdir/App/FooBar
/var/www/yourappdir/App/Foo/Bar
/var/www/yourappdir/App/Foo/Bar/Baz
```

But if you do

```
"psr-0": { "App\\Foo\\": "" }
```

It will be able to address just

```
/var/www/yourappdir/App/Foo
/var/www/yourappdir/App/Foo/Bar
/var/www/yourappdir/App/Foo/Bar/Baz
```

Comment: That would make app/src/Acme, right? Ideally I want to do app/models/Acme.

Comment: Your edit works great :) Although, one last thing...why would this cause class not found exceptions? `"App\\Models\\MyNamespace\\": "app/models/MyNamespace"` when trying to create a new `App\Models\MyNamespace\Thing;`?

Comment: Look in autoload_classmaps.php to see if you still have them there and if they are not conflicting. Your namespaced should not show there, just the namespace root folder in autoload_namespaces.php.

Comment: It's in the classmap file as `'App\\Models\\MyNamespace\\Test' => $baseDir . '/app/models/MyNamespace/Test.php'` and my composer.json has this entry in the psr-0 field: `"App\\Models\\MyNamespace\\": "app/models/MyNamespace"`. It works after dump-autoload. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: You still have the "autoload" "classmap" pointing to that dir, you must choose one or another. An option is to put your namespaced models in a different directory.

Comment: Here's an extract from my composer.json, but removing the app/models entry from the autoload.classmap section changes nothing... https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7534644

Comment: Nevermind! I think I solved it :) It will pick up anything in app/models with the namespace App\Models, subnamespaces get picked up too! Here's a Gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7535872

Comment: You seem to develop under windows, because that autoloading will not work with Linux - path names are case sensitive there. If you have a class "App\Model\Foo", it must be in an path "App/Model/Foo.php", not "app/model/Foo.php".

Comment: Sven, my servers are all Linux, it would be a fail to not make it right for both. And namespaced directories are meant to be upper and lower cased: http://puu.sh/5msSE.png. Take a look at the psr-0 autoloading standard: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md. Also left part is namespace, right is directory: app/models/MyNamespace/User.php, that's the file path.

Comment: The PSR-0 standard does not specify any case-insensitivity, but because it defines a transformation from the class name to the file name, it implicitly FORCES case-sensitivity on case-sensitive file systems. If you name your Class "App\Models\Foo", it cannot be found in a directory path ending with "app/models/foo.php" if the filesystem is case sensitive. Note that some autoloading systems do use lowercased plural directories like "models" to host singular uppercased classes containing "Model" - this is not compliant to PSR-0.